# Shutterstock - Automated multiple image download

Tags: macos, automation, imagedownload, shutterstock

Is there by any possible means any way to automate downloading multiple Shutterstock from a list of image IDs, the process is:

- Opening Shutterstock in the browser
- Pasting the images IDs in Shutterstock's search filed
- Opening each image in a new tab
- Confirming by pressing the download button
- Saving the file

Any suggestions?

Comment: They _do_ have an [API](https://developers.shutterstock.com). So you could use it as long as you are in line with their terms.

Comment: From a basic user perspective, I'm looking for a simpler solution ex: macros in browser etc

Answer (score 1):

To build off of what @Alladinian said above, the Shutterstock API makes it pretty simple to license & download a list of image ids as long as you have a user account and subscription. The specific guide you're looking for is [here](https://developers.shutterstock.com/documentation/licensing-and-downloading).

Answer (score 0):

No, theres no simple solution to downloading multiple images forusers.  This is clearly deliberate and it is wrong.  Users paid for images.  If they are worried about proliferation they should keep authentic users out of this and have way of going after misusers